# execute programmatically stored procedures with different parameter values

Tags: t-sql

I have stored procedure 
getList(@date datetime)

how programmatically execute stored procedure for differend datetime values.

datetime each month for 3 years.

Comment: Programmatically in which programming language?

Comment: I assume he / she means SQL Server as we are dealing with sprocs and tsql.  Could be oracle though.  Same concept look for a function that can add days / months/ years to the current date.
In SQL Server there is DATEADD().

Comment: t-sql programming language, in MS SQL Server

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do - can you rephrase ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,
        @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT  @StartDate = '01 Jan 2005',
        @EndDate = '31 Dec 2007'

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    PRINT @StartDate
    EXEC getList(@StartDate)
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @StartDate)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one month to the current date?

```
DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: im not sure what you mean, you have a date right?  All you have to do is take that date and add one month to it.  EXEC(@YourDateParameter)  SELECT @YourDateParameter = DATEADD(month, 1, @YourDateParameter)